# Problem: The python still reads the serial data coming from arduino after closing its port. Serial port cannot be closed

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial, toplevel

I'm new in tkinter, using python 3.4. I'm developing a GUI using Toplevel windows, and fetching serial data from Arduino. The only problem here is whenever the Button for "home" is clicked from "class PETwithSC", the python still reads data in class StartPage and closing the GUI. I need to close the serial port after clicking the home button. Please help. Thank you!

Here's the code

```
    from tkinter import *
    import serial
    import time

    class StartPage() 
        def __init__(self,master)
             self.master = master
             self.master attributes('-fullscreen','true') 

             self.button = Button(self.master, command=self.pageOne)
             self.button.pack() 

        def pageOne(self)
             self.master.withdraw()
             self.pick = Toplevel(self.master)
             self.game = PETwithSC(sef.pick)

    class PETwithSC()
        def __init__(self,master)
             self.master = master
             self.master attributes('-fullscreen','true')

             ###### Home button
             self.button = Button(self.master, command=self.home)
             self.button.pack()

             self.data = StringVar()
             self.label = Label(self.master, textvariable = self.data)
             self.label.pack()
             self.master.after(1000,self.serial)

        def serial(self)
             self.ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600,timeout=0.1)
             self.ser.write(b'1') ##commanding the arduino to read the smartcard info
             self.info = self.ser.readline()
             self.data.set(self.info)
             self.master.after(1000,self.serial)
             print (A)

        def home(self)
             self.ser.close()
             self.master.withdraw()
             self.pick = Toplevel(self.master)
             self.game = StartPage(sef.pick)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = Tk()
        myGUI = StartPage(app)
        app.mainloop
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `self.serial()` is running in a loop: `self.master.after(1000, self.serial)`, and it is opening the serial port each time: `self.ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600,timeout=0.1)`, just closing the serial port and `self.master.withdraw()` wont stop the next 1 run of `self.serial` from opening it again. Try just closing the port after every use:

```
def serial(self)
         self.ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600,timeout=0.1)
         self.ser.write(b'1') ##commanding the arduino to read the smartcard info
         self.info = self.ser.readline()
         self.ser.close()                   #closing here
         self.data.set(self.info)
         self.master.after(1000,self.serial)
         print (A)
```

And removing it from `self.home()`:

```
def home(self)
         self.master.withdraw()            #rather than here
         self.pick = Toplevel(self.master)
         self.game = StartPage(sef.pick)
```

Also, typo:

```
self.game = PETwithSC(sef.pick)
```

should be:

```
self.game = PETwithSC(self.pick)
```

Hope this helps